# Custom Buddypress Profile Page Set as Landing Page (BP_DEFAULT_COMPONENT)

Tags: php, wordpress, buddypress

I'm trying to make a custom Buddypress profile tab and make it so it is the landing page of a users profile. I have defined the tab in functions.php:

```
// Profile home tab

function profile_tab_overview() {
      global $bp;

      bp_core_new_nav_item( array( 
            'name' => 'Overview', 
            'slug' => 'overview', 
            'screen_function' => 'overview_screen', 
            'position' => 40,
            'parent_url'      => bp_loggedin_user_domain() . '/overview/',
            'parent_slug'     => $bp->profile->slug,
            'default_subnav_slug' => 'overview'
      ) );
}
add_action( 'bp_setup_nav', 'profile_tab_overview' );


function overview_screen() {

    // Add title and content here - last is to call the members plugin.php template.
    add_action( 'bp_template_title', 'overview_title' );
    add_action( 'bp_template_content', 'overview_content' );
    bp_core_load_template( 'buddypress/members/single/plugins' );
}
function overview_title() {
    echo 'Overview';
}

function overview_content() { 
    echo 'Content';
}
```

Then I set it as the profile landing page in wp-config.php with:

```
//Change BuddyPress default Members landing tab.

define('BP_DEFAULT_COMPONENT', 'overview' );
```

If i change BP_DEFAULT_COMPONENT to a standard Buddypress profile page like 'profile' it works, but it doesn't with the custom page I have created. Anyone know why, or what I can do about it?

Answer (score 1):

This should correct the issue using BuddyPress 4.0+ :)

```
//Set Default Tab to Overview
define('BP_DEFAULT_COMPONENT', 'overview' );
add_filter( 'bp_is_active', function($retval, $component){
    if($component === 'overview') return true;
    return $retval;
}, 10, 2 );
```

Answer (score 1):

@Russ Powers fix worked perfect.. for every other account but yours. when i click your profile in buddypress dasboard i get 404 error when the address is: domain/members/you

if i would be using only:

```
//Set Default Tab to active
define('BP_DEFAULT_COMPONENT', 'active' );
```

it works fine. but with my custom tab i get 404 error.. no idea why. everything after /member/you/something works, but for every user that enters his profile /members/mynick there's an error.

and im using this action, so nobody goes straight to wp-admin

```
add_action( 'load-profile.php', function() {
    if( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) && function_exists( 'bp_core_get_user_domain' ) )
        exit( wp_safe_redirect( bp_core_get_user_domain( get_current_user_id() ) ) );
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

What version of BuddyPress are you using? An upgrade to 4.0+ may be needed -- please note this behavior may be expected. From https://buddydev.com/what-is-new-in-buddypress-4-0/

> Restoring the behaviour of BP_DEFAULT_COMPONENT
>
> BP_DEFAULT_COMPONENT constant is used to specify the default landing
>   page on a user’s profile when their profile
>   link(http://example.com/members/username/) is opened.
>
> In BuddyPress 3.0, when user front page(home screen) was added, the
>   behaviour changed. If the front page was enabled, this constant did
>   not work. To make it work, you had to disable the user front page.
>   BuddyPress 4.0 restores the suprimacy of BP_DEFAULT_COMPONENT again.
>   Now, It will work as expected.

Alternatively, you're using 4.0+, a downgrade may be needed: https://buddypress.org/support/topic/bp_default_component-no-longer-working/

> I’ve using define(‘BP_DEFAULT_COMPONENT’, ‘dashboard’ ); in my functions.php but it’s no longer working since a few updates ago. ....
>   Just rolled back to 3.2.0 and this has now fixed it.